# How do I practically use Raft algorithm

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed, raft

In the Raft paper, they mentioned that all the client interaction happens with the leader node. What I don't understand is that the leader keeps changing. So let's say my cluster is behind a load balancer. How do I notify the load balancer that the leader has changed? Or if I'm correct, is it that load balancer can send out client request to any of the node (follower or leader) and it is the responsibility of the follower node to send the request to the leader?

Answer (score 3):

After the voting finish, you will have a leader (new or old). It is the responsibility of the leader to notify all the nodes in the network to send heartbeats at a regular interval(smaller than the keep-alive time of network but bigger than the maximum round trip time) to all the nodes.

Your load balancer should update the leader every time it gets heartbeats. Load balancer will send data only to the leader as according to raft algorithm all client requests directly goes to leader only, other nodes can't send data but only acknowledgments to voting and append commands.

There is a really good presentation here on the same:- [Raft: Log-Replication](http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/#replication)

Comment: But in the paper, it also mentioned clients need not be only users, but the nodes in the system as well

Comment: @FaizHalde Could you please explain the question further. Here I am referring client as any entity who wishes to push data in the cluster. For your case it is load balancer

Comment: Well consider a cluster of 5 nodes behind a load balancer. All the client interaction happens through the load balancer. The load balancer can pass the request to any of the nodes in the cluster (followers as well as leader). But in case a follower gets a request, it immediately sends it to the leader. (why I thought of this was because according to the paper, a client can be one of the node in the cluster)

Comment: I think what they mean is that, client is anyone who could generate data. They kept a possibility open that nodes themselves might want to add a new log. But in your case log lines are always added by load balancer only. Passing them to any client seems semantically wrong as per Raft, although if implemented correctly it should still work.

Answer (score 3):

There are really two ways this can be done: either the load balancer needs to understand where the leader is or the followers can proxy requests to the leader.

There's nothing wrong with proxying client requests to the leader through a follower, and in fact there can be major benefits to it. Many Raft implementations allow clients to read from followers while maintaining sequential consistency. This can still be safely done with a load balancer sending requests to arbitrary nodes if the client keeps track of the last index it has seen and sends that with each request to ensure it does not see state go back in time. I won't write the full algorithm here, but this is described in the Raft dissertation which you should consult.

But using a load balancer in this manner can become unsafe in certain cases. If clients are allowed to send multiple concurrent requests, the load balancer could route those requests through different nodes and they could arrive at the leader out of order. This can be accounted for by attaching a sequence number to client requests and reordering requests on the leader. But to do so, the implementation has to include sessions to allow the leader to track per-client state.

Typically, though, Raft clients connect to specific nodes and stay connected to them for as long as possible to reduce the overhead of maintaining consistency while switching servers. If an implementation supports reading from followers, it can still be costly to switch servers since servers have to wait for state to catch up to maintain sequential consistency.